# HTML 5 form which send infos in a PHP e-mail

Tags: php, html, forms, email, send

I would use some help because I don't know what to do at all...
I created an HTML form (which isn't a problem) :

```
<form method="post" action="form-page.php" class="cta">
    <div class="row gtr-uniform gtr-50">
        <div class="col-8 col-12-xsmall"><input type="text" name="user_name" id="name" required placeholder="Votre nom"></div>
        <div class="col-8 col-12-xsmall"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Votre adresse e-mail" /></div>
        <div class="col-8 col-12-xsmall"><textarea name="user_message" id="msg" required placeholder="Votre message"></textarea></div>
        <div class="col-4 col-12-xsmall"><input type="submit" value="Envoyer." class="fit primary" /></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I created the file "form-page.php" which treat the form with this code :

```
<?php
    // We get the infos of the form
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name']; // Nom / Pseudo.
    $email = $_POST['email']; // e-mail.
    $user_message = $_POST['user_message']; // Message.
    //=========

    // We put the adress where the mail is going to be send.
    //P.S : "myemail@gmail.com" isn't MY email, I just put it here to hide my email :)
    $mail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    //=========

    // We filtrate servers to avoid bugs.
    if (!preg_match("#^[a-z0-9._-]+@(hotmail|live|msn).[a-z]{2,4}$#", $mail)) 
    {
        $passage_ligne = "\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $passage_ligne = "\n";
    }
    //=========

    // We define the subject of the mail.
    $sujet = "Suggestion ou bug de ton site, Pokemon Reality";
    //=========

    // We create the header of the email.
    $header = "From: \"$user_name\" $email".$passage_ligne;
    $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$passage_ligne;
    //==========

    // We create the message.
    $message = $user_message;
    //==========

    // Finally, we send the email.
    mail($mail,$sujet,$message,$header);
    //==========
?>
```

Buuuut... This doesn't work! After I press the button "Envoyer." of the form, I wait while the page is loading and I see an error :
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kzWV.png)
[ERROR2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXZB1.png)
I didn't touch to anything, and before that, I test it 3 times, and it send the mail, but there was a blank page.
So I want to fix the error, and then, I want to redirect the user to the form and say "Thank You !".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "I see an error" Do you expect us to guess what error you see?

Comment: what is your main issue? is it "not able to send mail " or "How to redirect user"?

Comment: RopAli Munshi it's both, I want to fix the problem of the email, and then, redirect the user because before, when it worked, I saw a blank page...

Comment: Here's the error I see : [link]http://www.noelshack.com/2018-46-6-1542466205-error.png[/link] It's just a blank page with those words...

Comment: And when I inspect the element, I see that error : [link]http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/46/6/1542466315-form-page.png[/link]

Comment: You can test it but the server is a bit slowly : [link]http://pokemon-reality.000webhostapp.com/#formulaire